# Growth of a particular sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions

Not sure if this is research level? While analyzing a particular algorithm, I came across the following series:
$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{3^{k}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}2^{2^{i}}}$

Is there a closed form expression that illuminates asymptotic values in terms of $m$ accurately? In particular, I am interested in how slow this function grows compared to $\frac{3^{m}-1}{2}$ (which is the summation if one sets the denominator in each of the sum term to $1$).

Possibly is there a function that approximates $f(m)$ where $f(m)$ is such that $S_{m} =(\frac{3^{m}-1}{2})^{f(m)}$?

Comment: For large enough k, the denominator can be rewritten more simply.  The result converges quickly, but otherwise gives me no clue as to a closed form.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.14

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the sum $S_m$ can be given in a more compact way as 
$S_m = 4\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{3^k} {2^{2^k}}.$ The limit should be a transcendental number, since the sum is extremely lacunary, so it seems unlikely that a closed for exists (since most closed form transcendental numbers are "named" constants").

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1/n!)$ is a lacunary sum with a transcendental value, yet it has what would generally be accepted as a closed form; I'm not objecting to your conclusion, just to the word, "so". 

Comment: Hi Igor, I am only interested in something that grows as fast as $S_{m}$ and not S_{m}$ accurately.

Comment: The sequence $S_m$ converges to some number between $2.83$ and $2.84$, so it doesn't grow very much...

Comment: $S_{m} −S_{m−1} = \frac{3^{m}}{2^{2^{m}−1}}$

Comment: Basically Gerry's and Igor's answer says it converges to a constant. ok.

Comment: Igor, I think your compact expression should have a 4 out in front instead of a 2 -- the OP's term for $k=3$, for example, is $3^3/2^{2+4} = 3^3/2^{2^3-2}$.  The problem is that the product index should really start with $i=0$ in order for the $k=1$ term to make proper sense -- if it did, then your expression would match.

Comment: @Barry: yes, you are right, I did not notice the start index.
@Gerry: I guess what I had meant to say is that most "closed form" numbers known to be transcendental have names, and it is unlikely that this is one of them...